# Should I use Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay in a nopcommerce Task?

Tags: nopcommerce

I am coding a Task in a plugin to nopcommerce. The Task must download a catalogue from a website (https://data.icecat.biz/export/level4/). If the download fail for some reason, I want my program to wait for a minute and then try again a couple of times.

e.g

```
while(notTiredOfWaiting)
{
   try{
      // my download stuff here
      return data;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(60000);
       // or
      Task.Delay(60000);
   }
}
```

My problem is that nopcommerce is some kind of blackbox, which starts and run my task. The "easy" solution is to use Thread.Sleep(), but I don't know if any other important processes runs on the same thread. I have tried Task.Delay(), but it doesn't seem to work in my implementation.

I known that Thread.Sleep versus Task.Delay() is a hot topic on SO, but I am asking for a specific answer for what is best practice in nopCommerce.

Edit.

The task is using IScheduleTaskService.

Comment: Are you using the `IScheduleTaskService`? Or are you creating your own taskscheduling?

Comment: @max. I use IScheduleTaskService.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best option for the retrying operation is a [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), you doesn't need to worry about nopcommerce threading behaviour and you let .net to manage the threading stuff, you can use something like:

```
void Retry(){
    if(notTiredOfWaiting)
    {
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((cb) => { Retry() }, null, 60000, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Icecat is a quite big catalog, so I'm not surprised you're getting trouble with it.

You could change your algorithm to something like:

- Set your task to run at short intervals, for instance every 15 minutes.
- Try to acquire a lock at the beginning of the task; if the lock is taken then the previous task is still running, just return without processing.
- If the lock is not taken, acquire the lock, and check the last time the process ended. If enough time has passed, run your task (1 day, 1 week, or the amount of time you may need between downloads). You need to store the last time somewhere: you can use one of your own tables, or a custom setting would do just fine.
- If the task was successful, save the new ending time.
- Release the lock.

Maybe you would like to add a limit to the times you retry. And some logging.

```
// Sample pseudocode
if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj)) {
    try {
      if (EnoughTimeHasPassed())
      {
         DownloadIcecat();
         SaveLastFinishingTime(now);
      }
    }
    finally { Monitor.Exit(lockObj); }
}
```